# Prettify line numbers come out of div

Tags: css, prettify

The line numbers for prettify come out of the div:

[image: example outside]

I realize I can fix this with a margin but if there are a large number of lines they will still overflow. Is there anyway to non-statically keep these numbers inside the `<pre>`?

EDIT:
I have already tried playing with the list position by setting it inside, which breaks the layout of the code:

[image: example break]

[image: example break 2]

EDIT 2:
I'm using [this CSS theme](http://demo.stanleyhlng.com/prettify-js/assets/themes/bootstrap-light/prettify.css) with color changes.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-75" id="codeView">
    <div class="theme-{{{ $syntax }}}" id="codeTheme">
        <pre class="prettyprint linenums"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using [this CSS theme](http://demo.stanleyhlng.com/prettify-js/assets/themes/bootstrap-light/prettify.css) with color changes.

Comment: Please show your HTML too?

Comment: I added my HTML above